# What is the behavior of erasing the `end()` of a `std::list`?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I need to remove an element from a `std::list` after finding it with `std::find`. What is the behavior of calling `std::list::erase` with the `end()` of the list? My case is something like this:

```
std::list<T> mylist;
T value;
std::list::iterator it = std::find(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), value);
std::list::iterator next = mylist.erase(it);
```

[cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/erase/) says:

> If position (or the range) is **valid**, the function never throws exceptions (no-throw guarantee).
>   Otherwise, it causes undefined behavior.

but what I don't know is whether `end()` is considered valid there.

Comment: `end()` is one past the last element.

Comment: cplusplus.com is likewise outside the bounds of reputable sources. See cppreference.com instead.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The internet is outside the bounds of reputable sources. See the language specification instead.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Hmm, if we're in a glass house… anyway the wiki site is pretty well maintained by interested users, the same crowd as on this site. cplusplus.com on the other hand is closed. They focus on SEO to get links from Google, at the expense of accuracy.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Also, [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) doesn't mention any preconditions on the arguments to `erase` at all, so doesn't help with this question.

Comment: That's true, Mike. I checked cppreference.com and it doesn't say anything about what iterators are accepted as arguments.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That site uses the vague (and arguably incorrect) term "valid", but the library specification (C++11 23.2.3) uses the more specific term "dereferenceable" - meaning that the iterator must refer to an object. The past-the-end iterator is not dereferenceable, so erasing it gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: +1, also I think that the web has a worse issue than being *vague*, as `valid` is a term that is used in the standard and `end()` yields a *valid* iterator (i.e. the web page is not *vague*, it is **wrong**)

Comment: Actually, the library specification uses "valid" as well (e.g. for insertion, where an `end()`-Iterator is ok), but it explicitly says "valid *and* dereferencable" as a requirement for single-iterator-erase.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for. I don't have access to the specification. Do you know if it is the same in C++03?

Comment: @Janoma: Yes, it's the same in C++03.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't. Trying to erase `end()` results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

end() Returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end iterator in the list container and not the last object in the list.

By deleting/erasing end, you are deleting outside the range of your list. Your code should be:

```
std::list<T> mylist;
T value;
std::list::iterator it = std::find(mylist.begin(), mylist.end(), value);
If(it!=mylist.end())
  std::list::iterator next = mylist.erase(it);
```

Also if find() fails to find a value in your list it will return the end iterator, it is basically telling you that the value you are searching for is outside of your list (not in you list)

Comment: There is no past-the-end element in a container. `end()` returns a past-the-end **iterator**. In general, a past-the-end iterator does not have to refer to an element, although in many situations it in fact does.

Comment: Mad? I hope I didn't come across that way.